# How to create a bar plot with long horizontal error bars?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

[image: example plot]

I'd like to emulate the blueish background lines from the given image. Can someone tell me how to do so using Matplotlib?

Basically, it's a less complicated version of [this](https://github.com/raacampbell/shadedErrorBar).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using a stretched 1D image to draw the bands. The image gets an extent to fill the complete width and the desired height.  The `vmax` for the color mapping is set a bit higher to avoid too light colors, which would be too similar to the white background.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# create some test data
N = 40
x = np.linspace(-3, 3, N)
values = np.random.normal(0, 2, N)

error_bands = np.array([2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2])
plt.imshow(error_bands.reshape(-1, 1), extent=[-10, 10, -3, 3], origin='lower',
           cmap='Blues_r', vmin=error_bands.min(), vmax=error_bands.max() * 1.4, alpha=0.3)

plt.axhline(0, color='blueviolet', lw=3) # horizontal line at x=0

plt.bar(x, values, width=(x[1] - x[0]) * 0.8, bottom=0, color='blueviolet')

plt.gca().set_aspect('auto')  # removed the fixed aspect ratio forced by imshow
plt.xlim(x[0] - 0.3, x[-1] + 0.3) # explicitly set the xlims, shorter than the extent of imshow

plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

PS: A simpler approach, replacing `imshow` with some calls to `axhspan` drawing horizontal bars over eachother, using a small alpha:

```py
for i in range(1, 4):
    plt.axhspan(-i, i, color='b', alpha=0.1)
```

[image: alternative plot]